# How to give libusb 0.1.12 permissions for Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, libusb

I have to use libusb in my Android project. So far I have read alot on the internet that it is not so easy to use libusb with Android. I read something about init.rc and ueventd.rc and that I have to give some permissions for the usb. But because I am Android beginner I wanted to ask whether you could give me some more details how to make libusb work on Android. What are the steps needed to be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does "mount usbfs /proc/bus/usb" help?

Comment: I tried the command mount -t usbfs none /proc/bus/usb in the adb shell while I am connected to my ARCHOS 101 G9 via USB. But then I get the error: "mount: mounting none on /proc/bus/usb failed: Device or resrouce busy". What is the matter? Can anybody help?

Comment: When Android detects a USB device connected, it may give it root-only read-write permissions. So, is your Android device rooted?

Comment: No it is not rooted. That is the point. Is it possible to make libusb work on an unrooted android device ?

Comment: I believe that you need root access to configure the udev subsystem so that some device gets some specific permissions when plugged in.

Comment: Yes I think I will have to root my device altough I don't want to.